# Efficient storage / search algorithm for date range availability

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, search, data-structures, date-range

#### Background

I'm providing a map-based search for paddle boards, including searching by date - think "check in" / "check out" dates in a hotel search, where only hotels available for that entire date range are included in the results.

I have availability data for a couple years, (updated daily) for each paddle board. A paddle board is either available on a day (for 12 noon pick-up) or not available (meaning somebody is picking it up at 12 noon and will drop it off the next morning).

There are hundreds of thousands of paddle boards, so storing separate records for each day's availability for each is untenable (e.g., 350k paddle boards w/ 2 years availability data results in over 250 million rows).

#### Technology

I'm using Postgres 15, and I can add extensions, if necessary. I also have Redis available in the stack, in case the best solution involves non-RDBMS.

The app is very read-heavy, so large / expensive indexes are OK, within reason.

#### Initial Idea

My initial idea for storage and efficient searching involves storing availability data in a char field, for each paddle board, in a format like this: `AAANNAAAANA` (730 chars long, where `A` represents "available" and `N` represents "not available", with a static starting date (e.g., Jan 1, 2023)). Given a search date range (e.g., pick up on Jan 20 / drop off on the morning of Jan 25), I can construct a regexp search (e.g., `^.{19}A{5}`) and achieve decent performance... but... I feel like there's something more ideal.

For example, if I was working with a nested tree structure and wanted to get all offspring nodes of a given node, I could use an algorithm, like Modified Preorder Tree Traversal, to make easy work of an otherwise nightmarishly slow problem. Is there no such concept / mathematical solution to the kind of problem I'm describing?

#### Question

My question is, aside from the regexp solution I've come up with, are there any algorithmic solutions that are widely used to solve problems like this? For example, I looked into segment trees and some other data structures, not completely diving into any particular one, but I couldn't find anything that I deemed to be at least a **semi-ideal** solution to the problem. I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't involve really low-level hacking; something that's relatively expressive / maintainable, and where the main filtering work takes place in the database (vs in application space).

Comment: What are your typical searches going to be like? Will there be frequent searches for availablity across all time and space? Or mostly for the user's local region and recent times? Is it important that the result returns immediately (ex. user interaction) or can it be delayed (ex. reports)? Can query results be easily cached?

Comment: The middle ground is weekly (36M rows, 7 chars), monthly(8.4M rows, 31 chars), or quarterly (2.8M rows, 92 chars).

Comment: Instead of that char array thing, you should consider a `datemultirange`

Comment: Hotel searches are indexed first by location, which narrows the search to a few hundred hotels or so (typically), and then each one is checked for availability.  Availability information for hotels can be complex, including different prices and room types depending on itinerary, number of guests and children, etc.

Comment: @Bergi - wow, thank you! I didn't know `datemultirange` existed - it's new in PG 14 - this is **the** database solution. Unfortunately, my ORM (Django) doesn't support it, but I'm going to look into what it will take to write support for it.

Comment: @orokusaki I would recommend *against* `datemultirange` for this application. Making one row per paddleboard means you cannot store any additional information about each checkout. Who checked it out? What condition was it returned? What price did they pay? Were they late?

Comment: @orokusaki They're better than char arrays, but I fully concur with Schwern that *the* proper solution is to store one row per checkout. Easier to index, more efficient to update, easier to work with, better supported by your ORM.

Comment: @Schwern I just saw your reply (re: `datemultirange`) - for this application, that's preferable - we're getting availability data from a third party (1-2 times per day, per paddle board), without any specifics (other than dates available). Even if we were storing data about the specific checkouts, we'd still denormalize the values like this, for quick search. So, having a built-in Postgres type adaptation that can be indexed and provide the kind of functionality that I was prepared to replicate (via regexp) is perfect.

Comment: @Bergi see my reply, just a moment ago, to Schwern - we're not storing the transaction data, only availability data, and we're getting it one full batch at a time (vs inserting date ranges here and there into each paddle board's availability data).

Comment: @Bergi I was able to quickly write Django support for `datemultirange`, using only couple methods, since Django already supports the Postgres range fields, and it's working well. I can now filter, expressively, using: `queryset.filter(availability__contains=DateRange(...))`

Comment: @orokusaki I see, for that use case (in particular, never updating individual availabilities but always the whole series) the `datemultirange` might be ok. Notice that regarding data volume, it might not actually be that much better than a separate table or even the char array, you should test that. I have no idea how indices work on `datemultirange`, but if they suffice, go for it!

Comment: @Bergi thanks again. I think `datemultirange` is going to work, at least for now - we've only got 69k rows at the moment, but once we import this pile of data and increase that number to 350k+, that'll be the real test. But yeah, the biggest consideration is the very read-heavy aspect of it, namely not needing to poke at the individual dates, since we aren't managing the bookings themselves, so we can just grab the sequence a couple times a day, for each row.

Comment: @Bergi if you wouldn't mind putting your suggestion into a simple answer, I'll accept it, so that others might stumble across it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My initial idea for storage and efficient searching involves storing availability data in a char field, for each paddle board, in a format like this: `AAANNAAAANA` (730 chars long, where `A` represents "available" and `N` represents "not available", with a static starting date)

Using a character string for this is rather unwieldy. Nicest to work with, and following the best practice of database normalisation, would be to store the availability data in a separate table - with one entry per availability, per non-availability, or per date for which the status is known, depending on your modeling.

However, for your use case - in particular, never updating individual availabilities but always the whole series, always reading the whole (or at least a large part of the) series, and not ever needing to store additional data per checkout - a non-atomic representation might be ok and likely even faster.

- One approach would be to use a [bit string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html), which is smaller and has more appropriate operators available than the character string. Afaics, it does not provide suitable indexing capabilities.
- Next would be using an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) of dates, i.e. `date[]`, each representing a non-availability (which I guess are less common than availabilities). This probably takes much more space, but you can build a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-GIN) to search for arrays containing specific dates or overlapping with specific date arrays.
- Finally, Postgres 14 introduced [multiranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN), representing a set of non-overlapping ranges (or, if you want, a range with gaps). Using a `datemultirange` would be fitting especially if most checkouts of boards are for multiple sequential days, not just a single day. They offer  similarly useful operators, and [can be indexed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING) to search for containment and overlaps with other (multi)ranges.

Answer (score 1):

> There are hundreds of thousands of paddle boards, so storing separate records for each day's availability for each is untenable (e.g., 350k paddle boards w/ 2 years availability data results in over 250 million rows).

250 million rows can be handled, with some care, and we can likely reduce that by at least an order of magnitude.

Your proposed solution is, effectively, trying to make your own indexing system. Regex searches over a database are typically quite slow. And by cramming all checkouts into one row you cannot store any information about each checkout: who checked it out, what price did they pay, what condition was the board returned, etc.

Instead, use a conventional table and rely on indexes and 50 years of cumulative relational database development.

We can ***drastically*** reduce the number of rows by assuming paddleboards will spend most of their time sitting around waiting to be checked out (you can verify this assumption). Instead of storing the state of each paddleboard for each day, only store the dates when they are checked out. Use the [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) type. This lets us use [range operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

(Note: I would recommend *against* `datemultirange`. Any solution which tries to cram all checkouts into one row means you cannot store information about each checkout. Who checked it out? What condition was it returned? What price did they pay? Were they late?)

(Note: Consider using a tsrange, timestamp range, instead and defaulting the time to noon. Assuming the pickup/dropoff time will *always* be noon is a business requirement and can change at any time. Avoid hard coding it into your schema. While you can change the column type later and convert the data, it will be painful with that much data.)

```
create table paddleboards (
  id serial primary key

  -- and other information about each paddleboard
  -- who owns the paddleboard?
  -- where is it located?
  -- what condition is it in?
);

create table paddleboard_checkouts (
  paddleboard_id integer not null references paddleboards(id),
  in_use daterange not null

  -- and other information about this checkout
  -- who checked it out?
  -- what condition was it returned?
);
```

Then [index](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) `in_use` and `paddleboard_id`. These indexes will make these queries fast even as the amount of data gets larger. Instead of scanning the whole table, it can search the index. They are (often literally) the search trees you're wanting.

`paddleboard_id` can be a normal [b-tree index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-BTREE). However, `in_use` should use a [GIST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPE-GIST) because it supports [important range operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html#GIST-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE) like intersection (`&&`).

```
create index paddleboard_checkouts_fk on paddleboard_checkouts (paddleboard_id);
create index paddleboard_in_use using gist (in_use);
```

Here are some examples of queries the indexes will cover.

```
-- When is a particular paddleboard in use?
-- This will use paddleboard_checkouts_fk
select in_use
from paddleboard_checkouts
where paddleboard_id = 12345;

-- What paddleboards are checked out this week?
-- This will use paddleboard_in_use
select paddleboard_id
from paddleboard_checkouts
where in_use && daterange('2023-05-29', '2023-06-02');

-- What paddleboards are available this week?
-- This will use paddleboard_in_use
select paddleboard_id
from paddleboard_checkouts
where not in_use && daterange('2023-05-29', '2023-06-02');

-- Is this paddleboard available this week?
-- This will probably use paddleboard_checkouts_fk to narrow
-- the rows to just one paddleboard then linear search the few
-- remaining rows.
select paddleboard_id
from paddleboard_checkouts
where paddleboard_id = 12345
  and not in_use && daterange('2023-05-29', '2023-06-02');
```

---

Since your data will continuously grow, you may wish to consider [partitioning the table](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-table-partitioning-scale-postgresql) by year or perhaps month. This won't necessarily improve performance, but it will make it easier to drop old data and keep the table from continuously growing.

The complete data can be mirrored into a [data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse). This is a database which is optimized for storing and searching extremely large amounts of data. For example, [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).

Finally, if necessary for performance, you can add a cache for the results of common queries. It's likely most of your queries will cluster around a few months or weeks in the future.

Use the data warehouse for high-latency [business intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence) tasks which need to see the whole range of data such as reports, statistics, and so on. Use the PostgreSQL database for low-latency tasks such as serving web requests. Use the cache to decrease latency even further.

Comment: Thanks. I also looked into using a date range, but the reality is, about 50% of checkouts will be for 1 day, and there will be about 60 ranges in front of the current date, per paddle board. It brings the 250M down, but it's still 10s of millions of rows, looking ahead, and that table will continue to grow by 10-25 million rows each quarter, unless we continuously prune old records. I was hoping there was some kind of mathematical / algorithmic solution, yet unknown to me, that didn't involve simply brute force searching by date range (whether stored as a range or as single dates).

Comment: @orokusaki Indexes are the search trees you're looking for; indexes often are literally a b-tree. The database will not need to do a brute-force search, it will use an applicable index to narrow the results. The efficiency of the index is more important than the number of rows. The size of the table will have an impact, so I've added a section about how to manage a table which continually grows: data warehousing, partitioning, and caching.

Comment: If data partitioning / warehousing is necessary before the parent object reaches 10s of millions, let alone even 1 million, that feels like a mistake. When we're talking about needing to look through 50 million rows of "checkouts" every time somebody drags the map on the page, we're going to be in that scenario almost immediately. Doesn't an optimized / denormalized value seem precisely appropriate, here (e.g., `datemultirange`)? I realize, we wouldn't attempt to store transaction data in such a table, but from a pure availability / search standpoint, does that seem like a bad idea?

Comment: @orokusaki It's not necessary to partition/warehouse before reaching 10s of millions, but it will make maintaining the database easier for operations which do need to search or rebuild the whole table (for example, schema and data migrations). The database does not need to look through 50 million rows every time, it will use the indexes. I think there's a misunderstanding about indexes, [do you understand how database indexes work](https://use-the-index-luke.com/)?

Comment: I do understand indexes. Simply including indexes doesn't automatically solve the problem. If I was indexing a single field on a table that I planned to query using that field, then I would expect the index to solve the problem. For example, using a `paddleboard.available_on` and searching via that. Because we're talking about a many to one relationship from `checkout`, I'd be using a `checkout.date` b-tree index to find date intersections of **many** checkouts (60+ for **each** related `paddleboard` - if my map shows 50k paddleboards, then PG is working with 3 million of objects in the index.

Comment: To clarify, this is higher order design problem, which is why I was referencing other higher order solutions (e.g., MPTT), rather than a simple database optimization problem. The problem is that we have **many** checkouts **per** paddle board (a continuously growing number), and we're searching for paddle boards, and we need the results in milliseconds, and we need to know, for each paddle board, is it available for all of the dates in the user-selected range. I'm leaving a comment on the OP in a moment as well (re: Bergi). I truly appreciate your help and discussion, btw.

Comment: @orokusaki It seems we're having an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you've asked about your solution, but haven't fully described the problem you're trying to solve. Please edit your question with all the relevant details, including some examples of the types of queries you wish to make. This still seems like something solved with indexing. Note the use of a GIST index on `daterange` for efficient range operations such as looking up which paddleboards are available within a given date range; there is an example in my answer.